# c# XML or alternative

Tags: c#, xml

I am developing a program to log data from a incoming serial communication. I have to invoke the serial box by sending a command, to recieve something. All this works fine, but i have a problem.

The program have to be run from a netbook ( approx: 1,5 gHZ, 2 gig ram ), and it can't keep up when i ask it to save these information to a XML file.

I am only getting communication every 5 second, i am not reading the file anywhere.

I use xml.save(string filename) to save the file.

Is there another, better way, to save the information to my XML, or should i use an alternative?

If i should use an alternative, which should it be?

Edit:
Added some code:

```
            XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
            xml.Load(logFile);

            XmlNode p = xml.GetElementsByTagName("records")[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < newDat.Length; i++)
            {
                XmlNode q = xml.CreateElement("record");

                XmlNode a = xml.CreateElement("time");
                XmlNode b = xml.CreateElement("temp");
                XmlNode c = xml.CreateElement("addr");

                a.AppendChild(xml.CreateTextNode(outDat[i, 0]));
                b.AppendChild(xml.CreateTextNode(outDat[i, 1]));
                c.AppendChild(xml.CreateTextNode(outDat[i, 2]));

                sendTime = outDat[i, 0];

                points.Add(outDat[i, 2], outDat[i, 1]);

                q.AppendChild(a);
                q.AppendChild(b);
                q.AppendChild(c);

                p.AppendChild(q);
            }

            xml.AppendChild(p);
            xml.Save(this.logFile);
```

This is the XML related code, running once every 5 seconds. I am reading (I get no error), adding some childs, and then saving it again. It is when I save that I get the error.

Comment: Please show some code, as I can't believe that your netbook is too slow to write data to a file every 5 seconds. Or do you want to read it faster and it only happens every 5 seconds? Please clarify...

Comment: xml.save - what type is your xml variable? i am not sure which C# API you are using.

Comment: I am using System.Xml.

I am getting the data and saving them in one thread, and displaying a graf in the other.

Some code is on the way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to look at using an [XMLWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.aspx) and building the XML file *by hand*. That would allow you to open a file and keep it open for the duration of the logging, appending one XML fragment at a time, as you read in data. The XMLReader class is optimized for forward-only writing to an XMLStream.

The above approach should be much faster when compared to using the Save method to serialize (save) a full XML document each time you read data and when you really only want to append a new fragment at the end.

**EDIT**

Based on the code sample you posted, it's the Load and Save that's causing the unnecessary performance bottleneck. Every time you're adding a log entry you're essentially loading the full XML document and behind the scenes parsing it into a full-blown XML tree. Then you modify the tree (by adding nodes) and then serialize it all to disk again. This is very very counter productive.

My proposed solution is really the way to go: create and open the log file only once; then use an XMLWriter to write out the XML elements one by one, each time you read new data; this way you're not holding the full contents of the XML log in memory and you're only appending small chunks of data at the end of a file - which should be unnoticeable in terms of overhead; at the end, simply close the root XML tag, close the XMLWriter and close the file. That's it! This is guaranteed to not slow down your UI even if you implement it synchronously, on the UI thread.

Comment: A combo of what you are suggesting here, and what Coding Gorilla is suggesting might just be the solution.

I am using a main thread to display the data, and this thread already recieves all of the data. Maybe i could write to the XML file from there. I will experiment with this.

Comment: @Kentora: while performing the logging on a separate thread may definitely improve performance in certain situations, in your case (reading data once every 5 seconds) should not be required. You must keep in mind that using a separate thread to do the logging you increase the complexity of the code, and also may add a bit of overhead required for synchronization. I'm not saying you should not do it but only that you should "optimize" incrementally.

Comment: I have tried running it in the same thread, but that made my UI unresponsive on netbooks. Thats why i am using a different thread

Comment: @Kentora, have you tried using the XMLWriter approach on the same thread and that was causing trouble?  How large are these fragments that you're writing every five second?  That doesn't make sense..

Comment: i have to put the thread to sleep for 2 seconds while waiting for serial data. That is why the reason why it is in another thread.

Comment: what I meant is that the logging and the reading of serial data need not be in separate threads (whether they are both running in the context of the UI thread, or another). Anyway, I trust you've solved the problem now..

Answer (score 1):

While not a direct answer to your question, it sounds like you're doing everything in a very linear way:

1. Receive command
2. Modify in memory XML
3. Save in memory XML to disk
4. GoTo 1

I would suggest you look into using some threading, or possibly [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)'s to make this more asynchronous.  This would certainly be more difficult, and you would have to wrestle with the task synchronization, but in the long run it's going to perform a lot better.

I would look at having a thread (possibly the main thread, not sure if you're using WinForms, a console app or what) that receives the command, and posts the "changes" to a holding class.  Then have a second thread, which periodically polls this holding class and checks it for a "Dirty" state.  When it detects this state, it grabs a copy of the XML and saves it to disk.

This allows your serial communication to continue uninterrupted, regardless of how poorly the hardware you're running on performs.

Answer (score 1):

Normally for log files one picks append-friendly format, otherwise you have to re-parse whole file every time you need to append new record and save the result. Plain text CSV is likely the simplest option.

One other option if you need to have XML-like file is to store list of XML fragments instead of full XML. This way you still can use XML API (XmlReader can read fragments when specifying [`ConformanceLevel.Frament`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2344bs2.aspx) in XmlReaderSettings of XmlReader.Create call), but you don't need to re-read whole document to append new entry - simple file-level append is enough. I.e. WCF logs are written this way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Miky Dinescu is one technique for doing this if your output **must** be an XML formatted file. The reason why is that you are asking it to completed load and reparse the entire XML file every single time you add another entry. Loading and parsing the XML file becomes more and more IO, memory, and CPU intensive the bigger the file gets. So it doesn't take long before the amount of overhead that has will overwhelm any hardware when it must run within a very limited time frame. Otherwise you need to re-think your whole process and could simply buffer all the data into an in memory buffer which you could write out (flush) at a much more leisurely pace.

Answer (score 0):

I made this work, however I do not believe that it is the "best practice" method.

I have another class, where I have my `XmlDocument` running at all times, and then *trying* to save every time data is added. If it fails, it simply waits to save the next time.

I will suggest others to look at Miky Dinescu's suggestion. I just felt that I was in to deep to change how to save data.